# I can't hide url bar from twa

Tags: google-play, progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity

this is app link in google play:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thetruthapplication.www.twa

and, this is assetlinks url:
https://www.thetruthapplication.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json

I built app with @bubblewrap/cli